# using allocatable arrays from modules in f2py

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, f2py, allocatable-array

I'm having issues with allocatable arrays in `f2py`. In the code below (stored in `mymod.f90`), I created two modules, `vars` and `worker`:

- `vars` stores and allocates the array `b`
- `worker` contains subroutines to work with this array from `vars`.

The first `worker`-subroutine adds a scalar to `b`. This works as expected. The problem is with the next routine that should add a vector of matching first dimension to the array `b`. The implemented subroutine `add_vector2` works, but needs the dimension of the input `vector` to be passed along.

What I need is a subroutine with only the vector as argument, like the commented-out subroutine `add_vector1`. This, however does not compile with `f2py` (but works with `gfortran`).

Here's the code:

```fortran
! =======================================
! MODULE TO STORE AND INTIALIZE VARIABLES
! =======================================
MODULE VARS
  IMPLICIT NONE
  SAVE
  INTEGER :: n1, n2
  DOUBLEPRECISION, ALLOCATABLE:: b(:,:)
CONTAINS

  SUBROUTINE ALLOC(n1in, n2in)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: n1in, n2in
    INTEGER :: i, j

    n1 = n1in
    n2 = n2in
    IF (ALLOCATED(b)) DEALLOCATE(b)
    ALLOCATE(b(n1,n2))
    b = 0d0

    DO i = 1, n1
       DO j = 1, n2
          b(i, j) = (i-1)*n2 + j
       ENDDO
    ENDDO

  END SUBROUTINE ALLOC
END MODULE VARS

! ===================================
! MODULE THAT PROCESSES THE VARIABLES
! ===================================
MODULE worker
    IMPLICIT NONE
CONTAINS

    ! ADD A SCALAR TO ALL VALUES
    SUBROUTINE add_scalar(x)
        USE vars, ONLY: b, n1, n2
        IMPLICIT NONE
        doubleprecision, INTENT(in) :: x
        INTEGER :: i, j
        DO i = 1, n1
            DO j = 1, n2
                b(i,j) = b(i,j) + x
            ENDDO
        ENDDO
    END SUBROUTINE add_scalar

    ! ADD A VECTOR TO EVERY ROW
    ! THIS ONE WORKS, but needs the dimension
    ! of the vector as input. Instead, it should
    ! use n1 for variables
    SUBROUTINE add_vector2(vector,n1in)
        USE vars, ONLY: b, n2
        IMPLICIT NONE
        integer, INTENT(IN) :: n1in
        doubleprecision, INTENT(in) :: vector(n1in)
        INTEGER :: i, j
        DO i = 1, n1in
            DO j = 1, n2
                b(i,j) = b(i,j) + vector(i)
            ENDDO
        ENDDO
    END SUBROUTINE add_vector2

    ! ADD A VECTOR TO EVERY ROW
    ! the call of this routine should not
    ! have any other arguments, the vector
    ! is supposed to have the right shape n1
    !SUBROUTINE add_vector1(vector)
    !    USE vars, ONLY: b, n1, n2
    !    IMPLICIT NONE
    !    doubleprecision, INTENT(in) :: vector(n1)
    !    INTEGER :: i, j
    !    DO i = 1, n1
    !        DO j = 1, n2
    !            b(i,j) = b(i,j) + vector(i)
    !        ENDDO
    !    ENDDO
    !END SUBROUTINE add_vector1

END MODULE worker
```

This can be compiled with

```
f2py -m mymod -c mymod.f90
```

In python:

```python
In [1]: import mymod
In [2]: mymod.vars.alloc(3,2)
In [3]: mymod.vars.b
Out[3]:
array([[1., 2.],
       [3., 4.],
       [5., 6.]])

In [4]: mymod.worker.add_vector2([1,2,3])
In [5]: mymod.vars.b
Out[5]:
array([[2., 3.],
       [5., 6.],
       [8., 9.]])
```

How can I get `add_vector1` (with the same arguments/call) to work with `f2py`?

**Edit 1:**

This is the error message from `f2py`:

```
#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
 ^
/var/folders/r_/b16rpth9643dx5csqdw29wn40000gn/T/tmpm_sqc9ce/src.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.6/mymodmodule.c:550:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'n1'
  vector_Dims[0]=(n1);
                  ^
/var/folders/r_/b16rpth9643dx5csqdw29wn40000gn/T/tmpm_sqc9ce/src.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.6/mymodmodule.c:614:32: warning: incompatible function pointer types
 assigning to 'f2py_init_func' (aka 'void (*)(int *, long *, void (*)(char *, long *), int *)') from 'void (*)(int *, int *, void (*)(char *, int *), int
*)' [-Wincompatible-function-pointer-types]
  f2py_vars_def[i_f2py++].func = b;
                               ^ ~

2 warnings and 1 error generated.
```

**Edit 2:**

One option might be to create a wrapper, such as this one (`wrapper.f90`):

```
module wrapper
    implicit none
contains

    SUBROUTINE wrap_add_vector2(vector,n1in)
        USE vars, ONLY: b, n2
        IMPLICIT NONE
        integer, INTENT(IN) :: n1in
        doubleprecision, INTENT(in) :: vector(n1in)
        INTEGER :: i, j
        DO i = 1, n1in
            DO j = 1, n2
                b(i,j) = b(i,j) + vector(i)
            ENDDO
        ENDDO
    END SUBROUTINE wrap_add_vector2
end module wrapper
```

However compiling this with `f2py -m wrapper -c mymod.f90 wrapper.f90` still causes the same problem that is `f2py` cannot compile `mymod.f90`. The whole thing should be usable as `numpy` extension.

Comment: What happens when you run `add_vector1`? How it "does not work"? Wrong results? Error messages?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention this. have edited the question.

Comment: f2py wraps the call automatically so that you don't see the `n1in` argument. Unless you have a specific motivation to have it removed, I don't see a specific direction. If you want a library that is callable by Fortran as well with "assumed shape arrays", you can define another routine that has the calling convention you wish.

Comment: The subroutine call has to stay the same, because it's used like this in other parts of the code. Writing a new wrapper would be ok, but I also get the same issue because f2py still fails at compiling this. I added an **Edit 2** in the question.